# Load and display an image via dialog window to edit it later (Python TKinter)

Tags: python, tkinter

I am currently developing a GUI via Tkinter in Python. The idea is to create an interface, which allows me to select two jpg or png formatted pictures from my computer, resize them and show them in two separate square frames. Once done, there is a third frame with the third button underneath, which is supposed to start an animation (sequential image transitions) with the further involvement of pictures 1 and 2. I have no problem with importing these images in frames. However, when I try to access my global image variable inside the function (which is bound to the button) to convert an image to the array of pixels, the compiler finds no value stored in the variable.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from tkinter import Canvas
from numpy import asarray
import numpy as np

window = Tk()
window.title("Image Transitions")
window.geometry("1200x800")
window.config(background="CornflowerBlue")
window.maxsize(1200, 800)

title1 = Label(window, text="Image 1", width=20)
title1.place(x=180, y=175)
title1.configure(bg="CornflowerBlue")

title2 = Label(window, text="Image 2", width=20)
title2.place(x=530, y=175)
title2.configure(bg="CornflowerBlue")

title3 = Label(window, text="Image Transitions", width=20)
title3.place(x=880, y=175)
title3.configure(bg="CornflowerBlue")

button1 = Button(window, text="Upload Image 1", width=20, command=lambda:browse_Image1())
button1.place(x=180, y=510)

button2 = Button(window, text="Upload Image 2", width=20, command=lambda:browse_Image2())
button2.place(x=530, y=510)

canvas1 = Canvas(window, width=300, height=300)
canvas1.pack()
canvas1.configure(bg="LightSkyBlue")
canvas1.place(x=100, y=200)

canvas2 = Canvas(window, width=300, height=300)
canvas2.pack()
canvas2.configure(bg="LightSkyBlue")
canvas2.place(x=450, y=200)

canvas3 = Canvas(window, width=300, height=300)
canvas3.pack()
canvas3.configure(bg="LightSkyBlue")
canvas3.place(x=800, y=200)

def browse_Image1():
    global image_first

    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(
    initialdir = "/",
    title = "Select a File",
    filetypes = (("2D - JPG", "*.jpg*"), ("2D - PNG", "*.png*"), ("all files", "*.*")))
    
    img = Image.open(filename)
    img = img.resize((300, 300))
    image_first = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)

    label = Label(window, image=image_first)
    label.pack()
    label.place(x=100, y=200)

def browse_Image2():
    global image_second
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(
    initialdir = "/",
    title = "Select a File",
    filetypes = (("2D - JPG", "*.jpg*"), ("2D - PNG", "*.png*"), ("all files", "*.*")))

    img2 = Image.open(filename)
    img2 = img2.resize((300, 300))
    image_second = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img2)

    label = Label(window, image=image_second)
    label.pack()
    label.place(x=450, y=200)

ImageA_Width, ImageA_Height = image_first.size
data_A_norm = asarray(image_first) / 255.0
data_B_norm = asarray(image_second) / 255.0

window.mainloop()
```

As far as I understand, to access an image stored in a variable, I need to call this function. However, in my case, it is not the solution, as the “Select file” window will be called again.

Here I need to do both things:

1. Execute the command: choose and import images by pressing a button.
2. Get access to the imported images stored in variables.

Any idea or concept of fixing this would be highly appreciated!

Comment: You're trying to use your two global image variables in top-level code, during the startup of your program.  No images could possibly have been selected yet!  *All* of the usage of those variables needs to be within the `command=` function of the third Button, that you talk about but seem to have omitted from your posted code.

Comment: But if I delete these global variables ``global image_first`` and ``global image_second``, images that are shown in frames are going to be white, aren't they?

Comment: I'm not saying to delete the global variables.  I'm saying that you have to refrain from using them until a point in time when they actually exist!